# Urn problem with two ways of expectation computation

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

Let $X$ denote the number of white balls selected when $k$ balls are chosen randomly from an urn containing $n$ white balls and $m$ blacks.

For $i＝1....k; j＝1....n$,

$$\begin{align*}
X_i&＝\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }i\text{-th ball selected is white}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
Y_j&＝\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if white ball }j\text{ is selected}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

Compute $E[X]$ in two ways by expressing $X$ first as a function of the $X_i$s and then of the $Y_j$s.

Sorry for the poor codes

Comment: So, what have you done to express the count for white balls selected in terms of :(a) the indicators whether each *selected ball is white*, or (b) the indicators whether each *white ball is selected* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the reasoning behind linearity of expectation and indicator random variables.

Let $X$ be the number of white balls from our k draws.
$$X = X_1 + X_2 + X3 ... + X_k$$
where $X_i = 1$ if the $i^{\text {th}}$ ball selected is white and $X_i = 0$ if black.
$$E[X] = \sum_{i} E[X_i]= \sum_{i} P(X_i = 1)$$
$$P(X_i = 1) = \frac{n}{n + m}$$
$$E[X] = \sum_{i}P(X_i = 1) = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}{\frac{n}{n + m}}\\= \frac{kn}{n + m}$$

And I think a very similar reasoning can be used for the second part of your problem.

Comment: Makes sense ！thank you for your answer.

Comment: Btw bro, do we need to treat it as conditional probability ？since the question didn't mention the "replacement",  Xi doesn't  seems to be a series of independent events

Comment: Let's take a look at $P(X_2 = 1)$
$$P(X_2 = 1) = P(X_2 = 1|X_1 = 1)P(X_1 = 1) + P(X_2 = 1|X_1 = 0)P(X_1 = 0)$$
$$P(X_2 = 1) = \frac{n-1}{n+m-1}\frac{n}{n+m} + \frac{n}{n+m-1}\frac{m}{m+n} = \frac{n}{n+m}$$

And a very similar argument can be carried out for $P(X_3 = 1), P(X_4 = 1),...$